# How to rotate a plane around a line that lies on it by alpha degrees?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, plane-geometry

I am not much of a mathematician and I hope I could get some help with my problem.

I have two points in 3D and they form a line. Using 3D programming I am slicing the volume with a plane. All I need for creating a plane here is a single point and a normal vector of that plane.
The thing is there are infinite planes that could fit the line. All those planes actually circle the line. My idea is to determine the plane normal with an angle variable.
So what I'm asking is how can I determine a plane normal with a given angle variable?

[image]

EDIT: Just to clarify my sketch: black line is a line formed with two points I have and red vectors are plane normal vectors that I'd like to determine with an angle (phi in the picture).

Thank you for any given help, m.k.

Comment: what do you know about vectors ? do you know how to find a vector normal to a given one ? etc.

Comment: @GCab Hi, I appreciate your interest. Since my line lies on a plane, all normal vectors are vertical/perpendicular to my line. Let's say my lines vector is p, and normal vector is n, my starting point was perpendicular vectors condition px * nx + py * ny + pz * nz = 0, but I'm not sure how to make that equation angle dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have two points $A,B$ on the line, then you have the vector
$\vec {AB} $ and the unitary vector
$$
{\bf t} = {{\vec {AB} } \over {\left| {\vec {AB} } \right|}}
$$

Now, as far as I understood, you have a plane containing those two points
(and the line through them) that you consider as the reference plane, i.e.
the plane about which to measure the rotation angle.

I do not know how you are going to "fix" that plane. Seems that you know how to determine
the unit normal vector to it (let's call that ${\bf n}$).

If not, let's suppose that you individuate such a reference plane by giving a third point ($C$)
contained in it.
Then take ${\vec {AC}}$ and the dot product $a = {\vec {AC}} \cdot {\bf t}$.
$a \, {\bf t}$ is the component of ${\vec {AC}}$  along ${\vec {AB}}$ , which when subtracted from ${\vec {AC}}$
$$
{\vec {AC'}}  = {\vec {AC}}  - a\;{\bf t}
$$
leaves the component orthogonal to ${\vec {AB}}$.
Normalize this to obtain 
$$
{\bf u} = {{\vec {AC'} } \over {\left| {\vec {AC'} } \right|}}
$$
which is normal to ${\bf t}$ and also in the reference plane.

Now 
$$
{\bf n} = \;{\bf t}\; \times \;{\bf u}
$$
is the unitary vector normal to the reference plane.
In case, change its sign, so to obtain the required direction for measuring the angle:
we are considering that the angle $\alpha$ starts from ${\bf u} \to \alpha =0$
and moves towards ${\bf n} \to \alpha =\pi /2$.

Therefore
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf u}' = \cos \alpha \;{\bf u} + \sin \alpha \;{\bf n} \hfill \cr 
  {\bf n}' =  - \sin \alpha \;{\bf u} + \cos \alpha \;{\bf n} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where  $ {\bf u}' $ lies on the rotated plane, $ {\bf n}' $ is normal to that, and both
are orthogonal to $ {\bf t}$.

What you are asking is $ {\bf n}' $.

Comment: first, thanks for the amount of time you took to answer my question. and to answer your question above, i am not planning on fixating the plane, i want to have an input parameter alpha and rotate the plane. i will need a day to try this out (programming troubles :P) and i'll get back to you then

Comment: @m.k.: If I can give a further suggestion, before starting and programming, try and make better clear what you have as input and what you are going to produce as output. So are you starting with a plane (what I called the "reference" plane) and two points on it ? how is the plane defined (by its equation = normal, or by three points, or ..), what is the direction of the angle ?, etc. ..

Comment: @G Cab i finally understood what you did here and it is exactly what i needed, so thank you

Comment: @m.k: good, and have a nice work !